# How To Detect If Image Finished Loading When Using `nuxt-img`?

Tags: javascript, html, image, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt 3 project using the Nuxt Image module, and want to fade in my images when they finished loading. The `nuxt-img` component does re-emit the `load` event, but I noticed that this event is not always emitted. After searching online I found out that this event is apparently not emitted when the image is pre-loaded or loaded from a cache. The solution I found is to first check the `complete` property. However, I do not know how to access this property when working with the `nuxt-img` component instead of a native image element. Is that even possible? And if it is not, how else can I detect when the image finished loading?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to fix it wrapping the `<nuxt-img>` component in a `<ClientOnly>` component.

See https://github.com/nuxt/image/issues/682, seems to be a "known", open at least, issue.